# How to replace sqlite file with a new sqlite file? ANDROID

Tags: android, database, sqlite, overwrite

Periodically my application must update the database.

This update may not be automatic. When user access the app, there will be a check if there is a new database available. After verification, if there is a new version will prompt the user if they want to update the database. Given permission, start the download of the new file sqlite, which will replace the old file.

The new file has the same structure as the old file, but with more rows in the table. In addition, the database contains only one table.

I'm looking for a viable solution to two days and found nothing that could help me.

Thank you in advance for attention!

Comment: What *specifically* is giving you trouble? You already described what you need to do in the second paragraph of your question.

Comment: @Taynã Bonaldo : What you describe sounds like you want to download a new database file. Instead, you can simply download the new data in whatever format (XML, JSON etc) then delete the existing data in the table and then insert the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change files that are distributed inside your `.apk`. You will need to download this additional file somewhere else, then in your code you will have to decide which one to use at the time it is opened.

Comment: Then there is another solution? I can read and copy the new records for the old database?

Comment: If the new database file exists (presumably you would save it in the [internal storage area](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)), then open that file instead of the one in your `.apk`. Just ignore the original one entirely.

Comment: But I can save this file anywhere? Should I delete the old file folder / data / data / app / databases / (if possible)?

Comment: Yes, you can save the new file in the internal storage area (see the link in my comment). You cannot delete the old file, since it is part of your `.apk`. Just ignore the old one if you have a new one.

Comment: Ok, now the last question ... in my class DataBaseHelper, the DB_PATH ceases to be a constant and will be a variable, right? And the new path must be stored in user preferences or something, right?

Comment: You don't have to store the new path anywhere. In your code that opens the database, do something like: if (new database exists) { open new database; } else { open default database }.

Answer (score 1):

once any `update` is available in `market` user will download it and if new version of your app its database version does't match `onUpdate` method is called you can override it and do what ever you want to do.

another thing you can copy your database at `data/data/databases/yourdatabase.db` by simply `FileOutputStream`